# How to get fully options at /proc/sys/net in docker's ubuntu

Tags: docker

I'm trying to reconfigure some network kernel settings at /proc/sys/net/core in my container.
But it seems some options are missing in docker ubuntu:14.04 so that i can't configure them.
example:

```
$ sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=262144
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max: No such file or directory
```

There're just a few options in my docker:

**In my Host's Ubuntu:**

```
$ ls /proc/sys/net/core/
bpf_jit_enable         message_burst           rmem_default           xfrm_acq_expires
busy_poll              message_cost            rmem_max               xfrm_aevent_etime
busy_read              netdev_budget           rps_sock_flow_entries  xfrm_aevent_rseqth
default_qdisc          netdev_max_backlog      somaxconn              xfrm_larval_drop
dev_weight             netdev_rss_key          warnings
flow_limit_cpu_bitmap  netdev_tstamp_prequeue  wmem_default
flow_limit_table_len   optmem_max              wmem_max
```

**In my docker's Ubuntu:**

```
$ ls /proc/sys/net/core/
somaxconn  xfrm_acq_expires  xfrm_aevent_etime  xfrm_aevent_rseqth  xfrm_larval_drop
```

I attempted to run docker with **--net=none/default** (I don't wanna use host) or **--v /proc/sys/net:/proc/sys/net** but nothing changes.

I read this from kernel.org: "/proc/sys/net ... You may see only some of them, depending on your kernel's configuration."

So is there any way to get fully options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Those files represent configuration of your host network stack, without `--net=host` you create a new network stack inside a container and files are 'overwritten' by container ones.

If you need access to host stack you might consider mounting it somewhere else, lets say /net using `-v /proc/sys/net/:/net` and then simply use `echo value > /net/my/file` instead of using sysctl.

Comment: I mounted as you suggested but the files in `/net/core` are still the same with `/proc/sys/net/core` in the container other than the host.
Furthermore, I want to change setting of NIC of container but not host's NIC. because I am trying to install a package that requires to change those files on container.

Comment: Remeber that you have only a virtual link inside a container, not a physical one. Most probably by modifying host NIC you will have expected behaviour inside container ( I am not sure about it though ).